# How to retrieve the users iOS Version using Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, version

Is there a way to retrieve what iOS Version an user is using while using my app? I am using titanium and was wondering if there was any way to tell that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is your friend -> [Ti.Platform.version](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Platform-property-version)

Answer (score 1):

`Ti.Platform.version` will return the full version. `Ti.Platform.name` will tell you if it's iOS (Titanium returns "`iPhone OS`" in that case.